# GPS location never aquired

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get the GPS location in android, and run an ASYNC task with the gps coordinates. My location class is not just stalling the app with gps on. I am not getting a gps coordinate back.

My activity which tries to get the gps location is:

```
public class FindBrewery extends ActionbarMenu {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        setContentView(R.layout.beer_location_list);

        String title = "Nearby Breweries";
        TextView topTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beerLocationTitle);
        topTitle.setText(title);

        //get user location

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        ///new code
        LocationManager mlocManager=null;
        LocationListener mlocListener;
        mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

        if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if(MyLocationListener.latitude>0)
            {

                double longitude = MyLocationListener.latitude;
                double latitude = MyLocationListener.longitude;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside gps if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //get gps results
                //construct url
                String url = "myURL";

                Log.d("urlTest",url);

                //async task goes here
                new GetNearbyBreweries(this).execute(url);


            }
            else
            {
                //not sure what to put here yet...
            }

        } else {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is Not Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }


        //new code end



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

MyLocationListener Class:

```
package com.example.beerportfoliopro;

/**
 * Created by Mike on 11/26/13.
 */
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public static double latitude;
    public static double longitude;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        latitude=loc.getLatitude();
        longitude=loc.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        //print "Currently GPS is Disabled";
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        //print "GPS got Enabled";
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}
```

I know it is getting stuck in MyLocationListenerClass because I am not getting to my toast at all.

Udate:

I tried adding getters to MyLocationListenerClass:

```
public double getLatitude(){

        return latitude;

    }

    public double getLongitude(){

        return longitude;

    }
```

But when Igo back to my activity which calls all this I try:

```
double latitude = mlocListener.getLatitude();
```

Bt I get a cannot resolve method error on getLatitdue()

Comment: you will get any exception,error or not?

Comment: Which permissions do you have in the Manifest?

Comment: How exactly do you know that you are not getting anything back?

Comment: Do this inside your `onLocationChanged`: `Log.d("new Location", "latitude: "+ loc.getLatitude()+ ", longitude: "+loc.getLongitude());`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

you are calling the Class instead (MyLocationListener)  of calling the instance of the class mlocListener

```
if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if(MyLocationListener.latitude>0)
            {

                double longitude = MyLocationListener.latitude;
                double latitude = MyLocationListener.longitude;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside gps if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //get gps results
                //construct url
                String url = "myURL";

                Log.d("urlTest",url);

                //async task goes here
                new GetNearbyBreweries(this).execute(url);


            }
```

try doing this :

```
if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if(mlocListener.latitude>0)
            {

                double longitude = mlocListener.latitude;
                double latitude = mlocListener.longitude;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "inside gps if", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //get gps results
                //construct url
                String url = "myURL";

                Log.d("urlTest",url);

                //async task goes here
                new GetNearbyBreweries(this).execute(url);


            }
```

This should work

Comment: that red squigly underlines lattitude and longitude and says, cannot resolve symbol

Comment: can you initialize lattitude and longitude in MyLocationListener class and set them to 0. also take out loc.getLatitude(); loc.getLongitude(); from onLocationChange()

Comment: Tried it, same thing nothing happens.

Comment: did you take off static ? you might need a getter method to get the values.

Comment: I took static off and it would not compile:

Gradle: non-static variable latitude cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: it thats there , try setting up getter methods. that might help you.